# Can't seem to get this right (Function call) - Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to write an app that goes through and selects a feat and adds that to the html file. When I have something that looks for a specific element to be true, it goes through the statements accordingly. But when say, it does not make the requirement, it goes through the process again (which it should), but then doesn't add it to the html. In fact, it just says "undefined".

Here's the code in question. (I've included a truncated version of the whole code.)

```
function feats(){
    var ft = prompt("Write your feat here.");
    var feat;
    switch (ft) {
        case 'alert':
            feat = "<b>Alert:</b> +5 initative. You cannot be surprised while you are conscious. Other creatures don't gain advantage on attack rolls against you as a result of being hidden from you.";
            initiative = initiative + 5;
            break;  
case 'defensive duelist':
        if (dex >=13) {
            feat = "<b>Defensive Duelist:</b> When you are wielding a finesse weapon with which you are proficient and another creature hits you with a melee attack, you can use your reaction to add your proficiency bonus to your AC for that attack, potentially causing the attack to miss you."
        } else {
            alert("You do not have sufficient dexterity for this feat. Try another one.");
            feats();
        }
        break;
        default:
            feat = " ";
    } 
    return feat;
}
```

feats() is the function that this switch/case statement exists within. It should return the feat at the end of the function, but it doesn't when dex is not greater than or equal to 13. So how do I have it return a different feat when the function is called again.

Comment: can you post the code for the whole function. it's hard to tell with jsut these few lines

Comment: Sure. Though it's rather long.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are not returning the function call `feats()`. The reason why this is necessary, is because otherwise the logic continues, breaks the case structure and `returns feat`. Since the variable `feat` is never assigned a value, you get the value of `undefined`. To fix this, you return the function, meaning the function will return the value of the callback, in this case the same function - recursive function.

Example: I manually set the variable `dex`, since that is not included in your code example.

```
var dex = 12;

function feats() {
    var ft = prompt("Write your feat here.");
    var feat;
    switch (ft) {
        case 'alert':
            feat = "<b>Alert:</b> +5 initative. You cannot be surprised while you are conscious. Other creatures don't gain advantage on attack rolls against you as a result of being hidden from you.";
            initiative = initiative + 5;
            break;
        case 'defensive duelist':
            if (dex >= 13) {
                feat = "<b>Defensive Duelist:</b> When you are wielding a finesse weapon with which you are proficient and another creature hits you with a melee attack, you can use your reaction to add your proficiency bonus to your AC for that attack, potentially causing the attack to miss you."
            } else {
                alert("You do not have sufficient dexterity for this feat. Try another one.");
                return feats();
            }
            break;
        default:
            feat = " ";
    }
    return feat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the line

```
feats()
```

inside the `else` statement to

```
return feats()
```

But it might be simpler to reorganize a bit, depending on your feelings about multiple return statements from a function.

```
function feats(){
    var ft = prompt("Write your feat here.");
    switch (ft) {
        case 'alert':
            initiative = initiative + 5;
            return "<b>Alert:</b>...";
        case 'defensive duelist':
            if (dex >=13) {
                return "<b>Defensive Duelist:</b>...";
            } else {
                alert("You do not have...");
                return feats();
            }
        default:
            return " ";
    } 
}
```

To me, at least, this reads much better.

Answer (score -1):

Place `feats();` outside your `ifelse` statement.

Comment: I think that would change the logic of what OP is trying to do

Comment: That would cause an infinite loop, I believe.

Comment: Otherwise he can create a different function that checks for the next step whenever dex is higher than 13. Or more code.